# Allow user to Edit Posts but not Add New?

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, capabilities

For one of my custom post types I want a specific user to be able to edit existing posts created by admin but not be able to Add New posts.

How can this be done?

If I define the user role as not being able to Publish it still allows them to add a new post and submit for review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to do something like this:

```
function hide_buttons() {
    global $current_screen;

    if($current_screen->id == 'edit-post' && !current_user_can('publish_posts')) {
        echo '<style>.add-new-h2{display: none;}</style>';  
    }
}
add_action('admin_head','hide_buttons');
```

See: http://erisds.co.uk/wordpress/spotlight-wordpress-admin-menu-remove-add-new-pages-or-posts-link for reference

Comment: One caveat here: The user will still be able to add a new post if they go to the page directly, this just removes the button, not the user's capability to add new posts.

Answer (score 6):

The previous answer only hides the menu item with CSS, and as @ezejielDFM points out, it won't stop users from *actually* being able to add posts.

Instead, when registering your custom post type, you need to set the `create_posts` value to `do_not_allow` (or `false` in Wordpress versions below 4.5) and crucially set the `map_meta_cap` to `true`.

```
register_post_type( 'custom_post_type_name', array(
    'capability_type' => 'post',
        'capabilities' => array(
        'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow', // Prior to Wordpress 4.5, this was false
    ),
    'map_meta_cap' => true, //  With this set to true, users will still be able to edit & delete posts
));
```

If `map_meta_cap` is left out, it defaults to `false` and although you've disabled the ability to **Add New** posts, you also won't be able to edit or delete existing ones either, so make sure to include that value.

Full credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16675677/988246) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: the problem with this approach is, that as soon as I include 'create_posts' in the capabilities array, I can't display the list of my custom post type, so I can't even edit them ...